# How can i setup Metric alerts in Azure on an App Service?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-metrics-advisor

I have set the metric  403 , which is when the App Service has stopped.
The issue is I dont seem to be getting any emails even though from another browser I try to hit the website and it says the site has stopped.

Is there a way I can test if firstly emails are being send and any errors in sending the metric alerts ?

Do i need to set up Azure Active Directory Domain Services wth selected users who would be the first respondents to the alert ?

```
I have setup an App Service , and I have set a metric alert according to this link:

      https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-create-new-alert-rule?    tabs=metric
```

Answer (score 0):

If all incoming requests results in HTTP 403 error this is due to an app exceeds the CPU (short), CPU (Day), or bandwidth quota, the app is stopped until the quota resets.

If the app Memory quota is exceeded, the app is stopped temporarily.

You need to increase or remove quotas from your app by upgrading your App Service plan.

Further Metrics for an app or an App Service plan can be hooked up to alerts.
Suggest you to see [Receive alert notifications document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-classic-portal)

Also you may want to know that App Service apps hosted in Basic or higher App Service plans support **autoscale**.

**With autoscale, you can configure rules that monitor the App Service plan metrics.**

Rules can increase or decrease the instance count, which can provide additional resources as needed. Rules can also help you save money when the app is over-provisioned.

For more details: see [How to scale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/autoscale/autoscale-get-started) and [Best practices for Azure Monitor autoscaling.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/autoscale/autoscale-best-practices)